# MySQL not equal, not in does not work

Tags: mysql

I have a table (**type** is `tinyint(1)`):

```
id | name  | type
-----------------
1  | John  | 1
2  | Peter | 1
3  | Bob   | 2
```

After calling a `SELECT * FROM user WHERE type <> 1` I get **0** rows. Bob's line should have been returned.
I've tried `NOT IN (1)`, `!= 1`, but no success.

Comment: What is the data type of the field **type**?

Comment: Works with `[int, varchar(255), int]` schema

Comment: @itsols type is tinyint(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the 3 type of queries Works in the following fiddle:
Whether it is int or text type, the query works:

Checkout the fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4bb1/1

and

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b070/2